# How to add icons in PyQt5 app in flatpak?

Tags: pyqt5, flatpak

I have small PyQt5 app: https://github.com/taunoe/tauno-serial-plotter

I got all the functionality to work on flatpak but icons are a problem. Tried different things, but i have no clue how to make them showup.

```
(base) taunoerik@pop-os:~/Documents/MyGitHub/tauno-serial-plotter$ flatpak run
org.flatpak.Tauno-serial-plotter /app/bin/python3
Gtk-Message: 15:15:29.163: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:15:29.199: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 15:15:29.199: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/tauno-plotter.svg', because: No such file or  directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/tauno-plotter.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/arrow_down.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/arrow_down.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/arrow_down.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/arrow_down.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/plus.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/plus.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/minus.svg', because: No such file or directory
qt.svg: Cannot open file '/home/taunoerik/img/minus.svg', because: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "Tried different things" -> *what* things?

Answer (score 0):

File names should be absolute. Like:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'icons/file.svg')
```

Note relative like this: filename = './icons/file.svg'